# How do I use collect::<HashSet<_>>.intersection() without the values becoming borrowed?

Tags: rust

I am looping loop over a `Vec<&str>`, each time reassigning a variable that holds the intersection of the last two checked. This is resulting in "expected `char`, found `&char`". I think this is happening because the `loop` is a new block scope, which means the values from the original `HashSet` are borrowed, and go into the new `HashSet` as borrowed. Unfortunately, the type checker doesn't like that. How do I create a new `HashSet<char>` instead of `HashSet<&char>`?

Here is my code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn find_item_in_common(sacks: Vec::<&str>) -> char {
    let mut item: Option<char> = None;
    let mut sacks_iter = sacks.iter();
    let matching_chars = sacks_iter.next().unwrap().chars().collect::<HashSet<_>>();

    loop {
        let next_sack = sacks_iter.next();
        if next_sack.is_none() { break; }

        let next_sack_values: HashSet<_> = next_sack.unwrap().chars().collect();
        matching_chars = matching_chars.intersection(&next_sack_values).collect::<HashSet<_>>();
    }

    matching_chars.drain().nth(0).unwrap()
}
```

and here are the errors that I'm seeing:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/bin/03.rs:13:26
   |
6  |     let matching_chars = sacks_iter.next().unwrap().chars().collect::<HashSet<_>>();
   |                          ---------------------------------------------------------- expected due to this value
...
13 |         matching_chars = matching_chars.intersection(&next_sack_values).collect::<HashSet<_>>();
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `char`, found `&char`
   |
   = note: expected struct `HashSet<char>`
              found struct `HashSet<&char>`
```

By the way, what is that first error trying to tell me? It seems like it is missing something before or after "expected" -- `<missing thing?> expected <or missing thing?> due to this value`?

---

I also tried changing `matching_chars = matching_chars` to `matching_chars = matching_chars.cloned()` and I get the following error. I understand what the error is saying, but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
error[E0599]: the method `cloned` exists for struct `HashSet<char>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/bin/03.rs:13:41
    |
13  |         matching_chars = matching_chars.cloned().intersection(&next_sack_values).collect::<HashSet<_>>();
    |                                         ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `HashSet<char>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/brandoncc/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/collections/hash/set.rs:112:1
    |
112 | pub struct HashSet<T, S = RandomState> {
    | -------------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `HashSet<char>: Iterator`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `HashSet<char>: Iterator`
            which is required by `&mut HashSet<char>: Iterator`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt at using `cloned()` was almost right but you have to call it after you create the iterator:

```rust
matching_chars.intersection(&next_sack_values).cloned().collect::<HashSet<_>>()
```

or for `Copy` types you should use the more appropriate `.copied()` adapter:

```rust
matching_chars.intersection(&next_sack_values).copied().collect::<HashSet<_>>()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the extra information about copied(). Now I have to figure out how to make the lifetime of matching_chars live until the last line in the function.

Comment: @Brandon regarding the lifetime error, see [Why is "the temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block" an error?](/q/65972165/2189130)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the signature of `HashSet::intersection` will make this clearer:

```
pub fn intersection<'a>(
    &'a self,
    other: &'a HashSet<T, S>
) -> Intersection<'a, T, S>
```

The type `Intersection<'a, T, S>` implements `Iterator<Item=&'a T>`. So when you collect this iterator, you get a `HashSet<&char>` as opposed to a `HashSet<char>`.

The solution is simply to use `.cloned` on the iterator before you use `.collect`, since `char` is `Clone`, like so:

```
matching_chars = matching_chars.intersection(&next_sack_values).cloned().collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

> By the way, what is that first error trying to tell me?

The error is telling you that it expects `char` *because* (due to) the original value for `matching_chars` has type `HashSet<char>`.

> I also tried changing `matching_chars = matching_chars` to `matching_chars = matching_chars.cloned()` and I get the following error. I understand what the error is saying, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Do you, really?

`str::chars` is an `Iterator<Item=char>`, so when you `collect()` to a hashset you get a `HashSet<char>`.

The problem is that intersection *borrows* the hashset, and since the items the hashset contains may or may not be `Clone`, it also has to borrow the set items, it can't just `copy` or `clone` them (not without restricting its flexibility anyway).

So that's where you need to add the `cloned` call, on the `HashSet::intersection` in order to adapt it from an `Iterator<Item=&char>` to an `Iterator<Item=char>`.

Or you can just use the `&` operator, which takes two borrowed hashsets and returns an owned hashset (requiring that the items be `Clone`).

Alternatively use `Iterator::filter` or Iterator::find`on one of the sets, checking if the others`HashSet::contains`the item being looked at. Fundamentally that's basically what`intersection` does, and you know there's just one item at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I really do understand what the error is saying about the borrowed char. You said I can use & to resolve my issue. I couldn't figure out where to add it in order to resolve my error, can you tell me? I tried &matching_chars before posting here, but it didn't help. Also, I'll try adding the cloned call after my interaction call to see how that works. Thanks again.

Comment: Adding a call to cloned() after the intersection does fix the issue, as you said it would. Now It is telling me that matching_chars doesn't live long enough to use it at the end of the function. I guess now I figure out how to use life times :-) I would still really appreciate knowing where to put the & in your second solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I don't know why I said I understood the error. I do not understand the trait part, I just understand the wrong type part.